# Search in a ListView doesn't work properly

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, search

I have a listView with about 30 items in it and have added a search function to it via an editText. When I type 'a' in the textfield everything that starts with an 'a' shows up on the list but when I type another letter the list disappears even tho the list contains an item with 'a' + the other letter i typed.

Another thing that confuses me is that there is an item in the list called IWU Trading and thats the only item I can search for, means that if I type 'I' + 'W' the item shows up in the listView. But if I type 'a' + 'r' an item that is named 'art' dosent show up.

My question(s).
How can I do to make this search function work?
Why does it act like it does?

My XML

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/selectCustomerTextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="@string/typeToSearch"
    android:ems="10"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"/>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/nextButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchEditText" 
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp" >
</ListView>
```

My code:

```
    private ArrayAdapter<Customer> _oldAdapter = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_pick);
    EditText searchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listView.setClickable(true);

    searchText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

    _oldAdapter = _phoneDAL.BindValues(this);

    listView.setAdapter(_oldAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
              String s = _oldAdapter.getItem(arg2).toString();
              _listViewPostion = arg2;

              Toast.makeText(CustomerPick.this, "Du valde: " + s, arg2).show();
        }
    });
}
```

The search method:

```
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        ArrayAdapter<Customer> _adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Customer>(CustomerPick.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, new ArrayList<Customer>());

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        int textLength = s.length();

        if(textLength == 0){
            listView.setAdapter(_oldAdapter);
            return;
        }
                for (int i = 0; i < listView.getAdapter().getCount(); i++)
                {
                    String word = _oldAdapter.getItem(i).getCustName().toLowerCase();
                    if (textLength <= word.length())
                    {
                        if(s.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(word.substring(0, textLength)))
                        {
                            _adapter.add(_oldAdapter.getItem(i));
                        }
                    }
                }
                listView.setAdapter(_adapter);
    }
};
```

}

My CustomerClass (private ArrayAdapter _oldAdapter = null;)

```
public class Customer {
private final int _custNumber;
private final String _custName;

public Customer(int custNumber, String custName){
    _custNumber = custNumber;
    _custName = custName;
}

public int getCustNumber() {
    return _custNumber;
}


public String getCustName() {
    return _custName;
}


@Override
public String toString(){
    return _custName;
}
```

}

Comment: Please add your oldAdapter class.

Comment: Check [this](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/buttons-on-list-view-with-easy-searching-in-android/)

Comment: That's a bad way to filter a `ListView`. If you're going to use the default `ArrayAdapter` then all you have to do is simply call `((ArrayAdapter)listview.getAdapter).filter(s);` from `afterTextChanged`.

Comment: I see no obvious mistakes.  But the problem seems pretty easy to debug: can't you log word, s.toString() and word.substring(0, textLength) and see what's going wrong precisely? Or use the debugger?

Comment: Hmm, i'll try to debug it. Can it be some sort of autoComplete function in the virtualDevice? *speculating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
((Filterable) listView.getAdapter()).getFilter().filter(s);
```

into the `afterTextChanged` method of the `TextWatcher`(after reading Luksprog's comment).